# Restkit version 0.20.0-pre2. : Issue:No key in post object.how to post?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, restkit

I have a post request with an array of values as input.The problem is that, the array has no key for values inside to post!.How to set the mapping ?

Have to post this

```
 "group_ids": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
        ]
```

How to map the value and do the post using restkit 2.0

Comment: There are always 3 values? is just the number or there is more data?

Comment: Will change the number of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a vast search and experiments found the way to solve the problem.
There is no need to add mapping to the values inside!

Just create an `NSMutableArray` in the response main object and then map it to the root key [that is `group_ids`] to the mutable array name.

This maps the values correctly and the post works fine